# How to POST params in android and GET data back as JSONObject?

Tags: java, php, android, android-volley

I have to POST username, key and another parameter to get data as JSONObject and show them in a RecyclerView. I'm using Volley Library in android, tried every possible way none of them is helping.. 
even though testing through Postman seems to work fine and I get data when i post those three parameters but I don't know what am I missing in android..

PHP code:

```
<?php

require("db/Db.class.php");





if(isset($_POST['key']) && isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['getMainCategory'])){

    $db = new DB();

    $username = $_POST['username'];

    $key = $_POST['key'];

    $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM oc_api where `username` = '$username' and `key` = '$key' limit 1 ");



    if(count($query) == 0){

        $json = ["error don't have permittion"];

    }else{

        $catigory = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `oc_category_description`,oc_category WHERE oc_category_description.category_id = oc_category.category_id and oc_category.status = 1 and oc_category.parent_id = 0 and oc_category_description.language_id = 2");

        $json = $catigory;

    }



    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    echo json_encode($json);

    return;

}



if(isset($_POST['key']) && isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['getSlideShow'])){

    $db = new DB();

    $username = $_POST['username'];

    $key = $_POST['key'];

    $slideShowId = (int)$_POST['getSlideShow'];

    $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM oc_api where `username` = '$username' and `key` = '$key' limit 1 ");



    if(count($query) == 0){

        $json = ["error don't have permittion"];

    }else{

        $banderSlideShow = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `oc_banner_image` where `banner_id` = $slideShowId and language_id = 2");

        $json = $banderSlideShow;

    }

    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    echo json_encode($json);

    return;

}



if(isset($_POST['key']) && isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['getAllNews'])){

    $db = new DB();

    $username = $_POST['username'];

    $key = $_POST['key'];

    $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM oc_api where `username` = '$username' and `key` = '$key' limit 1 ");



    if(count($query) == 0){

        $json = ["error don't have permittion"];

    }else{

        $catigory = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `oc_blog_article`,`oc_blog_article_description` WHERE oc_blog_article_description.blog_article_id = oc_blog_article.blog_article_id and oc_blog_article.status = 1 and oc_blog_article_description.language_id = 2 order by oc_blog_article.sort_order");

        $json = $catigory;

    }



    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    echo json_encode($json);

    return;

}



$json = ["error"];

header('Content-Type: application/json');

echo json_encode($json);



?>
```

JAVA code:

```
public static final String URL_PRODUCTS = "http://vinsmartangle.net/shop/myApi/index.php";

 private void loadProducts(final String user, final String api,final String no) {

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL_PRODUCTS,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {

                            //converting the string to json array object
                            JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);

                            //traversing through all the object
                            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

                                //getting product object from json array
                                JSONObject category = array.getJSONObject(i);

                                String id = category.getString("category_id");
                                String name = category.getString("name");
                                Category data = new Category();

                                //adding the product to product list
                                data.setCategoryNo(id);
                                data.setCategoryName(name);

                                        categoryList.add(data);

                            }
                            categoryAdapter = new CategoryAdapter(getActivity(),categoryList, Fragment_Payment.this);
                            recyclerView.setAdapter(categoryAdapter);


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();

                        }
                        catch (JsonParseException e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                        Log.d(TAG, "onErrorResponse: Error ", error.getCause());

                    }
                })
        {
            @Override
            protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

                params.put("username ",user);
                params.put("key",api);
                params.put("getMainCategory",no);
                return params;
            }

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String,String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");


                return headers;
            }
        };

        //adding our stringrequest to queue
        Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity()).add(stringRequest);
    }
```

Postman [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpXRu.png):

```
[
    {
        "category_id": "20",
        "language_id": "2",
        "name": "رمان",
        "description": "&lt;p&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;\/p&gt;",
        "meta_title": "رمان",
        "meta_description": "مثال لوصف القسم",
        "meta_keyword": "",
        "image": "catalog\/demo\/compaq_presario.jpg",
        "image_Icon": "",
        "parent_id": "0",
        "top": "1",
        "column": "1",
        "sort_order": "1",
        "status": "1",
        "date_added": "2009-01-05 21:49:43",
        "date_modified": "2019-07-03 01:53:35"
    },
    {
        "category_id": "83",
        "language_id": "2",
        "name": "خضروات",
        "description": "",
        "meta_title": "خضروات",
        "meta_description": "",
        "meta_keyword": "",
        "image": "",
        "image_Icon": "",
        "parent_id": "0",
        "top": "1",
        "column": "1",
        "sort_order": "2",
        "status": "1",
        "date_added": "2019-07-04 11:05:33",
        "date_modified": "2019-07-05 06:16:54"
    },
    {
        "category_id": "85",
        "language_id": "2",
        "name": "ورقيات",
        "description": "",
        "meta_title": "ورقيات",
        "meta_description": "",
        "meta_keyword": "",
        "image": "",
        "image_Icon": "",
        "parent_id": "0",
        "top": "0",
        "column": "1",
        "sort_order": "0",
        "status": "1",
        "date_added": "2019-07-04 11:06:41",
        "date_modified": "2019-07-04 11:06:41"
    },
    {
        "category_id": "90",
        "language_id": "2",
        "name": "عسل",
        "description": "",
        "meta_title": "عسل",
        "meta_description": "",
        "meta_keyword": "",
        "image": "",
        "image_Icon": "",
        "parent_id": "0",
        "top": "1",
        "column": "1",
        "sort_order": "0",
        "status": "1",
        "date_added": "2019-07-04 11:08:56",
        "date_modified": "2019-07-05 11:59:46"
    },
    {
        "category_id": "87",
        "language_id": "2",
        "name": "صناديق",
        "description": "",
        "meta_title": "صناديق",
        "meta_description": "",
        "meta_keyword": "",
        "image": "",
        "image_Icon": "",
        "parent_id": "0",
        "top": "1",
        "column": "1",
        "sort_order": "0",
        "status": "1",
        "date_added": "2019-07-04 11:07:43",
        "date_modified": "2019-07-05 11:59:30"
    },
    {
        "category_id": "57",
        "language_id": "2",
        "name": "فواكة موسمية",
        "description": "&lt;p&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;\/p&gt;",
        "meta_title": "فواكة موسمية",
        "meta_description": "",
        "meta_keyword": "",
        "image": "",
        "image_Icon": "",
        "parent_id": "0",
        "top": "1",
        "column": "1",
        "sort_order": "3",
        "status": "1",
        "date_added": "2011-04-26 08:53:16",
        "date_modified": "2019-07-03 01:52:47"
    },
    {
        "category_id": "89",
        "language_id": "2",
        "name": "مشروبات",
        "description": "",
        "meta_title": "مشروبات",
        "meta_description": "",
        "meta_keyword": "",
        "image": "",
        "image_Icon": "",
        "parent_id": "0",
        "top": "0",
        "column": "1",
        "sort_order": "0",
        "status": "1",
        "date_added": "2019-07-04 11:08:01",
        "date_modified": "2019-07-04 11:08:01"
    }
]
```

and when I run the app I get this exception:

```
W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value error at 0 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
        at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:101)
        at org.json.JSONArray.getJSONObject(JSONArray.java:525)
W/System.err:     at com.smart.mangojazan.Fragment_Payment$1.onResponse(Fragment_Payment.java:117)
        at com.smart.mangojazan.Fragment_Payment$1.onResponse(Fragment_Payment.java:105)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:82)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:29)
        at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:102)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7050)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
```

Comment: Code looks fine, have you debugged to see what's coming in response?

Comment: Okay so you are getting error when decoding the json .The API and volley are working fine .Use gson to decode json . And this will resolve your issue.

Comment: @AhmadAyyaz Yes. I'm getting response: ["error"]

Comment: @JawadAhmed It does not work because I'm not getting Json array, I'm only getting this string  "["error"]"

Comment: then your API is not sending proper response. Something's missing there. API should return proper response. Your code tries get JSONObject from JSONArray but there is no object inside array in your response and it is giving exception while parsing

Comment: @AhmadAyyaz I understand. what's confusing is I'm getting data from Postman but in java code it seems to me that getParams method is not getting executed or something because they must be sent to get data back. However thank you for your reply, I'll try more.

Comment: Print the response in onResponse

Comment: can you use okhttp instead of volley? I have faced these kind of issues with volley too

Comment: You have set $json = ["error"]; before sending the response in your backend code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue and it was pretty ridiculous actually.. there was a little space 
beside "username" in the first params.put which was causing this issue of not getting data and also causing an exception.. even though I double checked but don't know how i missed that.. Thanks for everyone who took time and tried to help me out. I appreciate that.

```
@Override
            protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
       //the line below was causing the exception. right side of "username " (space)
                params.put("username ",user);
                params.put("key",api);
                params.put("getMainCategory",no);
                return params;
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

you have done all your code and just before sending the response have set json=["error"];
**[don't forget to accept answer and upvote if the answer is correct or articulate (explain more) your question so that answerers can give more relevant answers]**

```
<?php

require("db/Db.class.php");
if(isset($_POST['key']) && isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['getMainCategory'])){
    //your code

    //remove below two lines from every if as it can be called commonly at last;
    //header('Content-Type: application/json');
    //echo json_encode($json);
}else if(isset($_POST['key']) && isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['getSlideShow'])){
    //your code
}else if(isset($_POST['key']) && isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['getAllNews'])){
    //your code
}else{
    $json = ["error"];
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are expecting JSONArray hence don't go for StringRequest instead use JsonArrayRequest available in volley. See this documentation: https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request

Your error log is also indicating

> java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Hence I suggest you try this:

```
JsonArrayRequest req = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL_PRODUCTS,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
             //.............
```

Since you are expecting a json array.

Comment: the response is JSONArray